# How to deploy a DataSnap/REST ISAP dll on IIS 7

Tags: rest, iis, sqlite, delphi

I am new to Delphi.

I recently created a DataSnap REST server application in Delphi XE7, and I want it to connect to my already existing mobile multi-platform application that I had previously created in Delphi XE7. The purpose of the DataSnap server application is to create a middle tier between the Enterprise server (SQL Server 2012) and the mobile application. I am using SQLite for local storage in the mobile application.

I have tried to deploy the DataSnap server onto IIS 7 using the steps in [this link](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/40873). 
This link has been the most promising of my research. Now my problem is that, after I have implemented all of the steps in the above link, when I run the virtual library in IIS7, instead of getting the actual aerver application, I am getting the algorithm of the application.

In IIS7, in the MIME Types, I have included the extension '**.pas**' with MIME Type '**text/pascal**'. When I run the browser, it gives me the algorithm of the application, instead of the Application itself.

How can I run the virtual library and get the application itself, instead of the algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delphi is a compiled language, just like C++. Your Web server doesn't compile your code for you; that's Delphi's job. Open your Delphi IDE and *compile* your project. Delphi will generate a DLL or EXE file. Put *that* file in your Web server's directory as instructed in the documentation you linked to. I'd start with the section titled "Test the ISAPI version with IIS 7.5."

This is *not* like PHP, where the server recognizes the source code and executes it instead of serving the file contents. The server does not execute Delphi source code.

Comment: WoW! Thank you so much, that works! :) been struggling a long time :)